# Trying to store values in dictionary from a data frame using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

```
#Names of columns in the dataframe 
featureList = df.columns
print(featureList)
#number of columns in the dataframe
noOfCol = len(df.axes[1])
print(noOfCol)
#number of rows
noOfRow = len(df.axes[0])
print(noOfRow)
featureList = df.columns
print(featureList)
#number of columns in the dataframe
noOfCol = len(df.axes[1])
print(noOfCol)
#number of rows
noOfRow = len(df.axes[0])
print(noOfRow)

#creating a dictionary for storing all the cols separately
#using for loop: way4
dfDic = dict()
colCounter = 0
for featureName in featureList:
  dfDic = {featureName:df.iloc[:,[colCounter]]} 
  colCounter +=1

print(dfDic)
```

This is my code and the following [image](https://ibb.co/d2gLKWw) is the result. I want to store the column values for all the features but only the last column is getting stored.

Comment: please provide the input data, the expected output and the error messages as **text**

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` or `numpy` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: It's probably how you assign to the dict.
This 
```dfDic[featureName] = df.iloc[:,[colCounter]]``` should fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply convert a Pandas dataframe to a dictionary using `df.to_dict(orient="list")`.

Comment: @Saba If it solved your question, please accept the answer.